# Worth all of these(phrase)

Tags: phrases

Buck, said in the movie to Captain America: (when Captain America tries to save his friend despite some costs)

> ''I dont know if I'm worth all of these Steve...''

I know the meaning, but did I get the phrase correctly? Can't find any result thru Google by the way

Comment: Your title says "worth all of **this**" but your question reads "worth all of **these**" – which are you asking about?

Comment: I don't know the context but **this** or **these** presumably refers to some objects that movie viewers can see, and they are likely to be objects of value.

Comment: The line is another, common example of the existential "this" pronoun to refer to some unmentioned but readily understood concept or thing.  It should always be "this" and not "these", e.g. *"I don't deserve **this**"*.   Because it's based on context, there's normally no way to tell from the single line of dialogue what "this" refers to.

Comment: Thx you guys, It's already answered below. By the way, I have changed the title and the highlighted question to make them parallel.

Answer (score 4):

From [fan-made transcripts](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War):

> **Bucky Barnes**: What's gonna happen to your friends?
>   **Steve Rogers**: Whatever it is... I'll deal with it.
>   **Bucky Barnes**: I don't know if I'm worth all this, Steve.
>   **Steve Rogers**: What you did all those years...It wasn't you. You didn't have a choice.
>   **Bucky Barnes**: I know. But I did it.

So the line reads: *"I don't know if I'm worth all this, Steve."*

Steve Rogers is in the middle of risking his own life to protect Bucky from the other Avengers and Black Panther.  Bucky is referring to everything that Steve is doing when Bucky says "this".

So what Bucky really means is something like:

> "I don't know if I am worth all of the effort and risks you are taking just to protect me, because I did many bad things and I don't deserve your help."

What Steve says next shows that Steve understands all of that even though Bucky only says "all this".

Comment: Yeah this is it! As I've said I get what Buck said. Thx man, you really nailed it, how did you get this dialogue hehe nice

Comment: Yes, it was misquoted in the question. To be worth something is the idiom.